# Sum over cell array of sparse matrices

Tags: matlab, optimization, cell, sparse-matrix

I have 100 sparse matrices of size *N-by-N*, where `N=65536`.

They have about 5.5M nonzero elements(0.13% of N^2) close to the diagonal.

They are stored in a cell array, `S{1}, ... , S{100}`, and I want to compute the sum `S{1}+...+S{100}`.

```
Sum=sparse(N,N);
for i=1:100
    Sum=Sum+S{i};
end
```

The above `for` loop code took about 25 seconds. Is there any way to optimize this code?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't use loops, and also avoids converting the matrices into full:

```
[ii, jj, vv] = find(vertcat(S{:})); % concatenate matrices vertically.
    % Get nonzero values (vv) with their row (ii) and column (jj) indices
ii = mod(ii-1, N) + 1; % convert ii to original row indices
Sum = sparse(ii, jj, vv); % this automatically adds values at the same ii, jj
```

Comment: This code looks fine. But in my computer, the first line took 200 seconds, and the last line took 450 seconds and then stopped because of memory shortage. :(